# How to make an action game with 3D graphics like Minecraft?

Tags: game-engine

i want to make an action game where the player is in a maze and while escaping he has to kill other player / monsters. The game will be available on Windows.
I don't know where to start.
I looked at C++ and DirectX9 but it's a little bit hard for me, XNA for C# is not supported anymore by Microsoft, GameMaker 8 Pro doesn't seems so complete.
Maybe a book to read will be good, hope in your answers.

Comment: This question is much too broad to be a good fit for StackOverflow. Read some books or tutorials on the subject and ask a question if you run in to a specific problem that you can't find an answer to.

Comment: May you tell me what book should i read?

Comment: I don't know about any specific titles but I'm sure you can find some Windows game development books at Amazon.

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you a kickstart, i'd recommend you to take a look at visual C# and openTK, maybe JitterPhysics

http://www.opentk.com/

http://jitter-physics.com/wordpress/

depending on your programming knowledge this could be all you need to start.
Also its allways a good idea to look at how other engines solve problems, for instance download the free version of unity and look at a view abstractions they make.